# Is this behaviour, producing OutputSizeLimit`Dump`encapsulateOutput, a bug?

Tags: front-end, bugs

**Bug introduced in 6.0.0 and fixed in 11.0**

---

The input

```
inequalities = {Y[5], Y[7], Y[9], Y[10], 
 155 + 27 Y[5] - 13 Y[7] - 65 Y[9] - 13 Y[10], 162 - 27 Y[5], 
 45 - 9 Y[7] + 43 Y[9] + 12 Y[10], 374 + 105 Y[9] - 51 Y[10], 
 1288 + 23 Y[7] - 759 Y[9] + 3 Y[10], 1 + Y[7] - Y[9] + Y[10], 
 3 + 3 Y[7] + 4 Y[9] - 2 Y[10]}

ToRules[
 Reduce[# >= 0 & /@ inequalities, Variables[inequalities], Integers]]
```

produces for me (MMA 10.0.1.0 on OS X) output beginning with `` OutputSizeLimit`Dump`encapsulateOutput ``.

Presumably this is a bug in Mathematica.

> Is it fixed in a newer version? Is there a good workaround?

Comment: Same result, 9.0.1 Windows. Setting "Maximum output size before truncation" in evaluation options in preferences seems to stop the error.

Comment: BTW, I meant setting it to some large enough value, or 0 (infinity). You can use the Preferences menu, or do directly in the notebook (or a block to make it temporary) using `SetOptions[EvaluationNotebook[], OutputSizeLimit -> ...]` or use `$OutputSizeLimit` directly...

Comment: It seems the output size limiting code is getting confused by the `Sequence` head (simpler example: `Sequence @@ ConstantArray[0, 1*^5]`), for a workaround perhaps use `{ToRules[...]}`.

Comment: I observe the same behavior with v8.0.4 on Win7 x64.

Comment: Same with 10.2 Win7 x64.

Comment: Reported internally as a bug. Thank you!

Answer (score 1):

This bug has been fixed in the just released [Mathematica 11.0](http://www.wolfram.com/mathematica/new-in-11/):

[image]